# Android WebView of local website manipulating the URL

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin, android-webview

When using an Android WebView I am able to load in my custom web application using the `view.loadUrl("https://example.com/assets/www/index.html")` method.

Where the webpage is stored **locally** in my android `assets`

However there is a slight issue. This will set the URL of my page to `http://example.com/assets/www/index.html`. What I would like to do, is to load my content using a much simpler URL such as: `http://example.com`

However I can't seem to find a solution for this other than hosting my website remotely.

Here is my current `Activity`:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var myWebView: WebView? = null

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val assetLoader = WebViewAssetLoader.Builder()
            .setDomain("example.com")
            .addPathHandler("/assets/", WebViewAssetLoader.AssetsPathHandler(this))
            .addPathHandler("/build/", WebViewAssetLoader.AssetsPathHandler(this))
            .addPathHandler("/res/", WebViewAssetLoader.ResourcesPathHandler(this))
            .build()
        initiateWebView(findViewById(R.id.webv), assetLoader);
    }

    private fun initiateWebView(view: WebView, assetLoader: WebViewAssetLoader) {
        myWebView = view;

        view.webViewClient = LocalContentWebViewClient(assetLoader)
        view.settings?.javaScriptEnabled = true
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true)
        }
        myWebView?.addJavascriptInterface(JsWebInterface(this), "androidApp")
        view.loadUrl("https://example.com/assets/www/index.html")

    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (myWebView?.canGoBack() == true) {
            myWebView?.goBack()
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }

}

private class LocalContentWebViewClient(private val assetLoader: WebViewAssetLoader) :
    WebViewClientCompat() {
    private val jsEventHandler = com.example.minsundhedpoc.JSEventHandler();

    @RequiresApi(21)
    override fun shouldInterceptRequest(
        view: WebView,
        request: WebResourceRequest
    ): WebResourceResponse? {
        return assetLoader.shouldInterceptRequest(request.url)
    }

    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest): Boolean {
        val url = view.url
        // Log.d("LOG","previous_url: " + url);
        return false
    }

    override fun onPageCommitVisible(view: WebView, url: String) {
        super.onPageCommitVisible(view, url)
        jsEventHandler.sendEvent(view, "myCustomEvent");

    }

    // to support API < 21
    override fun shouldInterceptRequest(
        view: WebView,
        url: String
    ): WebResourceResponse? {
        return assetLoader.shouldInterceptRequest(Uri.parse(url))
    }

}
```

Comment: Marc, it's frustrating to have to add another note. Your posts are written in a rather needy style, and readers have to wade through a fair bit of begging to get to the question. Moreover, your posts are written in a slapdash manner, and need significant repair to make them readable. This is not an appropriate way to use Stack Overflow - it is not a chatroom.

Comment: @halfer i will rework my post to ensure that it lives up to the standard. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Note that the words `can't`, `don't`, `won't`, `doesn't`, `aren't`, `I'm`, `I've`, etc. are _contractions_ i.e. they are shortened versions of longer phrases. To be spelled correctly they need an apostrophe. Please use an English spell-checker in your browser (some like Firefox and Chrome come with one built in - you just need to set it to the correct language). Any variant of English (British, Canadian, Australian, US, Indian, etc) is fine.

Comment: Unfortunately there are two contractions (`can't` and `won't`) that will not be detected if they are misspelled: "cant" and "wont" are correctly spelled words, but they mean completely different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer to your question. No you can't do that.
of course there is will be work around such as VPN or tunneling

BUT think about it a minute. letting the user see a local website with a domain name ?

of course he will try to access it from the browser. and won't be able to do that.

And what if you want to update your website ? you will need to completely update the app. that's not practical.

Consider using a remote web hosting like [firebase hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting) it's for free and giving you 2 doamins (example.web.app) and (example.firebaseapp.com) and you can use any custom domain, there is a providers can give you a custom domain for free (strongly not recommend that as they can withdraw it any time) like [freenome](https://www.freenom.com/en/freeandpaiddomains.html) and for paid domain providers there is some cheap solutions like [cosmotown](https://www.cosmotown.com/#!/) and [dynadot](https://www.dynadot.com/domain/search.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is not really an 'Android question' but rather a 'domain settings' one. And the answer to it is the Domain Masking technique.

For your case, it should be relatively easy to implement. Firstly check if you have the `.htaccess` file and if there is no one - you should create it and upload it to where your site code is stored.

The main line of code in that file should be

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

In your case, it should look something like

```
DirectoryIndex assets/www/index.html
```

If there is no such a line in your `.htaccess` file you should add it.
This simple trick will redirect all the traffic from your plain domain URL name `http://example.com` to the `index.html` file you have specified there.

Moreover, you can specify a proper redirect in this file making all the users of your domain name access completely different domains. You can do it via

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^something/?$ /something/else/
```

This way each time someone accesses:
https://somedomain.com
the actual content that will be displayed will be for:
https://someotherdomain.com
while the URL will remain unchanged.

Maybe some more work will be required based on your actual settings and code but this is a pretty good place to start fixing this issue.

If you want to run the site from the assets folder of your android app - this method won't work because you have no apache running inside your app on your phone.

I don't think it is even possible to achieve what you want with regular WebView and AssetManager - the assets folder is a files folder and to use the file from it you have to have a use file from it by its relative path.

I guess you can create some sort of routing/redirecting system over the AssetManager or over WebView - but it will be quite difficult to make. But you can start by looking at how it is implemented in Apache with .htaccess - it is open source.

Comment: Hello :) the web application is not hosted on a remote website rather it is stored locally in the android assets. Will the htacess work there?

Comment: Oh... nope. It won't.

Comment: @MarcRasmussen - you haven't specified that a local website means that it is not some website you develop locally on your computer but a site from an android assets folder... It won't work like that. I will add a simple clarification to the answer

Comment: i am so sorry i can see that now i will update my question